# How to resolve Russian language encoding in java?

Tags: java, encoding

Constructing a String with value as ФФХЧЯЯЯЯэшЩтЯ .The string value is in Russian Language.

String russian=new String("ФФХЧЯЯЯЯэшЩтЯ");

Printing the string as below.
ФФХЧЯЯЯЯ�?шЩтЯ

so the э in the character set is not able to convert.

Tried with all the possible encoding types like, UTF-8,ISO-8859-1,ISO-8859-2,ISO-8859-3 and many things i have tried

```
public void setter(String attachment) {
        try {

            filename=new String(filename.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.filename= filename;
    }
```

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related? I only see plain java

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Attempts to "change the encoding" of a string like this are doomed to failure, I'm afraid. I would suggest you print out the individual UTF-16 code units to see *exactly* what's in the string. See https://gist.github.com/jskeet/fda32346c7600cfb1449b94907c03df5 for an example of code to do that. You could then include the results in your question.

Comment: Your code snippet wouldn't compile as is. I guess you meant to write `filename=new String(attachment.getBytes(),"UTF-8");` In any case, use a debugger and see if `attachment` is already "corrupted". In that case, you should make sure that wherever it comes from, attachment should come in UTF-8 format.

Comment: "attachment=new String(attachment.getBytes(),"UTF-8");" in this line i am converting filename by UTF-8 here i am not able to convert some Russian characters